# Question tag for "There will be."

Tags: tag-questions

What is the question tag for the two sentences below?

> There would be.
>
> There will be.

I got confused by the modal verbs and the exception of "there is/are".

> A) There would be, wouldn't it?
>
> B) There would be, isn't there?
>
> C) There will be, won't it?
>
> D) There will be, isn't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Externally, existential *there* is parsed as if it were the subject of its clause, so *there* is the subject used in tag questions; and the verb is the tensed auxiliary which heads the main clause:

> There would be, wouldn't there?
>   There will be,  won't there?
>   There has been, hasn't there?
>   There was, wasn't there?

In those cases where there is no auxiliary in the main clause, *DO* is used in the tag question:

> There followed three examples, didn't there?

But such situations are very rare; tag questions are mostly confined to colloquial registers, and you don't often encounter *there* with any verb but a *BE* construction in improvised speech.

Comment: Dear StoneyB, Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!